# Why doesn't 1/2 always equal the value of X's CDF at E[X]?

Tags: probability, distributions

Doesn't exactly half the probability fall on either side of the mean?

Comment: Some distributions like the [Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) don't even have an expected value, so this certainly wont hold true for all CDF's

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Doesn't exactly half the probability fall on either side of the mean?

No!

The value half the probability falls either side of (at least with continuous distributions) is called the ***median*** (with discrete distributions you have to rephrase as something like "at least half is equal to or above and equal to or below").

The mean is a different thing with a different definition, and in general mean and median are different.

Consider a distribution that has 99% of the probability at 0 and 1% of the probability at 100. The mean is 1, but 99% of the probability is below the mean.